# Android studio BLE Max Client Reach

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to read data from a BLE device 24/7. I am able to scan it and can get the data but when the device is not in the range, then it will scan every 30 seconds ( I have created a handler) and after 32 attempts the app will crash. I checked the log and I am getting the following error

```
can't register GATT client, Max client reached: 32
Register with GATT stack failed.
```

This is my code that that runs when the BLE device is disconnected

```
if(newstate = BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED) {
   if(mGatt !=null) {
     mGatt.close();
     mGatt = null;
   }
   queues.clear();
   handler.postDelayed(runnable = new Runnable(){
     public void run(){
      handler.postDelayed(runnable, delay) //3000ms delay
      BLEManager.getInstance().connectDevice(address) // device trying to reconnect 
     }
    }, delay);
   }
```

Any suggestions will be highly appreciated

Comment: This happens when the `BluetoothGatt.connect()` method is invoked and when you attempt to disconnect, the `BluetoothGatt.close()` method is not executed properly. Perhaps you doesn't implement the `BluetoothGattCallback` methods approprietly?

Comment: You are most likely not calling .close() on your BluetoothGatt objects correctly. In any case - you should instead just set `autoConnect` to true and leave it (don't call .close()). Then it will automatically re-connect when in range.

Comment: Thank you very much. The autoConnect did the trick

Answer (score 2):

First of all,
I'd suggest you to use [RxAndroidBle](https://github.com/dariuszseweryn/RxAndroidBle) or [Kable](https://github.com/JuulLabs/kable) for cleaner code.

Each device has a Gatt connection limit. To not reach that limit you have to close connection when you done with that Gatt object.